# jquery how to set jquery DOM name

Tags: jquery

I am studying about jquery and customize it. When I check stackoverflow.com source code by view source code in browser. I found this :

```
StackExchange.ready(function () {
        StackExchange.using("postValidation", function () {
            StackExchange.postValidation.initOnBlurAndSubmit($('#post-form'), 2, 'answer');
        });
```

how the write StackExchange.ready and its function like StackExchange.question.init, StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToQuestion etc

pls help me

Comment: You can find the JS for StackExchange here `Developer tools -> Sources -> cdn.sstatic.net -> Js`

Answer (score 0):

Something like -

`var yourCustomName = $(document);`

go ahead with - `yourCustomName.ready(function () {`

---

Stackoverflow has custom ready method -

```
StackExchange.ready=function(d){StackExchange.initialized.done(d)};
```

Comment: but there is no StackExchange = $(document); in StackExchange website as I study

Answer (score 0):

StackExchange is an object they have created consisting of functions

```
StackExchange {init: function, debug: Object, initialized: Object, ready: function, using: function…}
MarkdownEditor: function (a){var c=a.postfix||"";(j=StackExchange.options.site.isMetaStackOverflow||StackExchange.options.site.isChildMeta)&&(D=StackExchange.options.site.parentUrl||
anonymous: Object
captcha: Object
cardiologist: Object
chatAd: Object
comments: Object
debug: Object
editor: Object
gps: Object
helpers: Object
ifUsing: function (g,h,d){if("undefined"!==typeof d){if(c["u_"+d])return;c["u_"+d]=!0}StackExchange[g]?h():((d=a[g])||(d=a[g]=[]),d.push(h))}
imageUploader: Object
init: function (j){StackExchange.options=j;j.serverTimeOffsetSec=j.serverTime-(new Date).getTime()/1E3;e(j.site.name);$.ajaxSetup({cache:!1});StackExchange.init.createJqueryExtensions();
initialized: Object
inlineEditing: Object
inlineTagEditing: Object
loadJsFile: function (a){return n(k()+a)}
loggedIn: Object
navPrevention: Object
newsletterAd: Object
notify: Object
openid: Object
options: Object
postValidation: Object
prettify: Object
question: Object
ready: function (d){StackExchange.initialized.done(d)}
```

To view StackExchange object just type StackExchange in the console. You can find the code for stackexchange here

```
Developer tools -> Sources -> cdn.sstatic.net -> Js
```

---

To write a function like this you can do

```
var StackExchange = {
    init: {
        questions: function () {
            console.log("init")
        }
    },
    ready: function () {
        console.log("init")
    },
    debug: function () {
        console.log("init")
    }
}
```

Comment: pls can you tell me where they written it? in js file or other where ?

Comment: @shailendra They are written in here `Developer tools -> Sources -> cdn.sstatic.net -> Js` all files under this directory

Answer (score 0):

```
var Question = function () {
    this.ask = function () {
        // ....
    };
};
window.StackExchange = (function () {
    var question = new Question();
    return {
        // Add more here to your liking
        question: question,
        ready: $(document).ready
    };
}());

StackExchange.ready(function () {
    question.ask();
});
```

The best general advice I can give is 'study some patterns', like revealing module pattern.